# Where is the block heater on 99 Ford Taurus?

Tags: ford, heater, taurus

Where can I find the block heater to plugin in the hood. My car is a Ford Taurus 1999.

edit: Does it even have one?

Comment: It would depend on if it has a cold weather package installed or not.  They do not all come with block heaters.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the car. What engine, what market was it sold in? You may want to check your VIN using [this explanation](http://www.taurusclub.com/forum/124-taurus-sable-general-discussion/89988-96-08-owners-manuals-reading-vin-numbers.html#post1005081), or try [Ford VIN decoder](https://www.fleet.ford.com/maintenance/vin_tools/default.asp).

Answer (score 1):

The location of the plug depends whether it was installed at the factory, by the dealer, or the third party. One of the most common places for the block heater plug on the third generation Ford Taurus (1996–1999) is the driver’s side opening in the lower part of the bumper (with spring-loaded cap):

[image: Image of the block heater plug]

If it is not visible from the front (either as pictured, under the bumper, or cut into the bumper) it could be somewhere in the engine compartment, easily accessible from the top with the bonnet open.

And, of course, it may be so that it isn’t there at all. It should be fairly easy to track down. One of the most common kinds of block heaters on these Fords is the simple contraption installed in place of one of the [core plugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_plug), so by checking all of them it can be easily seen where and if it is there, and where leads its wire harness.